# Remove active class when user scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the above effect. When I click on individual menu items, the active class changes correctly. However, I want to remove all active classes when I scroll the page. In summary, the active class only has to change when clicked, and delete when the user scroll the page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        var $href= $(this).find('a').attr("href");
        var offset = $($href).offset().top;
                $(window).off('scroll');
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: offset + 'px'
        },500)


        $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('a').addClass('active')

        return false;

  })


      $(window).scroll(function() {
                    $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
      })

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m7pL4y2p/5/

Comment: If am i correct scrolling to 2nd color will change menu color also as selected?

Comment: No, background color of menu must be the same - white

Comment: the problem comes from this instruction `$(window).off('scroll');`. you need to readd the scroll handler before returning false in the click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove scroll and use wheel method.

I hope the below simplified code helps you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a').click(function(event) {
    var offset = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: offset + 'px'
    },500);     
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $(window).on('wheel', function(event){
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just like this effect I wanted to get :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with this solution which is not optimal but it seems to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('li').click(function() {
      var $href= $(this).find('a').attr("href");
      var offset = $($href).offset().top;
      $(window).off('scroll');

      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: offset + 'px'
      },500).promise().then(function() {
         // Animation complete
         console.log('complete');
         // Need a timeout because this handler is fired before scrollTop reach the final position
         window.setTimeout(function() {
           $(window).scroll(removeAllActiveClasses);
         }, 100);
      });

      $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('a').addClass('active')

      return false;

   });

   function removeAllActiveClasses() {
     $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
   }

   $(window).scroll(removeAllActiveClasses);

});
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7pL4y2p/36/)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. THANKS!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "window" to "document" just as in:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
                $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
  })
```

Comment: It works, when you load the page first time. Then when you click on an item again and scroll down, the active class remains at element li

Answer (score 0):

try to change this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
         $('ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
  })
```

to this you have to bind scroll

```
 $(window).bind('mousewheel',function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');    
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the active class remains the same as in my example above.

Comment: @hetious Edited check this

Answer (score 0):

Well, so it requires another aprox. The fact is that "annimation" is an asynchronous function, so you need a flag (automScr) that tells the on window scroll program to delete the class or not.

So you put atomScr to true when pressing over menu item, and set to false when the scrolling animation is done.

Keep a look on the "console.logs" messages.

Hope this works!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var automScr=false;
$('li').click(function() {
            automScr=true;
    var $href= $(this).find('a').attr("href");
    var offset = $($href).offset().top;
            $(window).off('scroll');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: offset + 'px'
    },500,null,function(){setTimeout(function(){automScr=false;},1)});


    $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active')

    return false;

})


  $(document).scroll(function() {
     if (!automScr){
      console.log ("no automscr");
                $('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
      }else {
      console.log ("automscr");
             }

  })

})
```